# Is there a way to use a parameter named 'code' in my Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

I am using Azure Functions as the back end for a static web app. In order to connect to a 3rd party platform, I need to go through the OAuth Authorization Code flow, which includes the third party calling my function with a query parameter named `code`. It seems that Functions uses this for some internal auth purposes which I am not using, and I get a 500 response before it even hits my code - I've determined the problem is having a parameter named `code`. Is there a way to make this work with Azure Functions?

I am using Python for my function but I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a workaround of a page in the static web app with some JavaScript that renames the parameter and redirects to the function:

```
let url = new URL(window.location)
url.pathname = "/api/redirect" // The url for the function to handle the request
let query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
let code = query.get("code")
query.append("authorization_code", code)
query.delete("code")
url.search = `?${query.toString()}`
window.location = url
```